# Display SharePoint list forms(New/Edit/Display Forms) within SPFX React web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, spfx, react

Is it possible to display/render SharePoint list forms(New/Edit/Display Forms) within SPFX React web part as it is(Not in modal dialog or new window)?

Comment: If you are ok with panel then go for pnp control IFramePanel.You need to provide url.  https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/IFramePanel/

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to render listforms in webparts directly, but if you look into PnP controls, you will find React List Form WebPart to render list form. It dynamiclly renders the list form with Display,New & Edit modes. The webpart is pretty much new.

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-list-form